# Should I make a suggestion to senior management over office dinner?

Tags: careers

The senior management is coming to have a dinner with us this July. There is only one security expert in our company right now, as I have recently been certified as a security engineer; I want to share some workload with the security expert.

Is it appropriate to make this suggestion over dinner?

Comment: We can't tell you - this is almost completely dependent on your company dynamics. Sometimes, dinner will be a "working meal" where this is appropriate. Other times, senior management may not want to talk shop at all.

Comment: In any case you will have to react to the atmosphere. If anyone congratulates you for your certification, you might accept the praise and then add, it has taught you how important security experts are and how this task might be to big for a company that size. But I would not force the topic on anyone.

Comment: What does the existing security expert say. Does he think that he nneds help? I woudl clarify that beofre even conteemplating talking to management

Comment: @Mawg, yeah, I almost forgot to involve this security expert. Will definitely talk to him first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Steps**:

1. Check on your company policy to see if there is any stipulations about approaching management (sometimes there is a chain of command or a comment box or helpdesk approach, just check and see)
2. Assuming there isn't anything against it then I would approach the security engineer first and talk with him so that it will be a unified agreed on front when approaching management.  So much better to approach things as a team than one person suggesting with questionable other side.  Management might also ask if you talked to the security engineer first as well in which case you can say yes.  Obviously don't "decide with him" just see if he is good with the idea should management decide in favor of it.
3. Pick your time to approach management carefully and be sure it's during casual mingling time and not a prep time or in front of everyone creating an awkward moment.  Also be mindful if alcohol is served to not catch them drunk (sure it shouldn't happen, but everyone has vices and you may find that one with who you are talking with)
4. Lastly, don't look like a stalker.  I know you are observing and taking in information to find the right time, but you want to approach professionally and casually(according to the dinner style) and not come off like someone who has waited all day to corner you in this moment.

Good luck.

**P.S.** If you find something during #1 then that is what you must do to work the situation out.

**P.P.S.**  You also want to be on the same page with your supervisor or anyone who may perceive it as "stepping on toes" for you to go directly to management to discuss.

Comment: very good point. I will definitely to talk to my direct manager first before I try anything.

Comment: why the down vote?

Answer (score 2):

**Senior management is not the place I would start with this request.**

Going directly to senior management is typically a break with normal protocol. It can be justifiable, but if it isn't clear that this is an issue where you need the seniors' ear, it may be received poorly.  (This isn't just about formal policy, but expectations as well).

There are several avenues I would explore before taking this up with senior management:

- **Talk to your boss.** A general request like "I think I could use these skills to benefit the company" is probably a better start than a well-formed idea.
- **Talk to the security expert.** As mutt suggests. But this may be more than just prep for your own conversation. If he is enthusiastic about the idea he might be a more effective advocate for it than you, since it's his area of expertise. There also might be initial opportunities to informally work together, which could strengthen your case.
- **Take advantage of any company support for career development or role changes**. There might be opportunities you aren't aware of.

In the end, you may need senior management, since your request might imply a change in the company structure. If so, the dinner may be a good opportunity, and mutt provides some excellent guidance about how to approach this. But I would pursue other channels first.